# Spring Zuul Eureka Security Authentication get user info from Zuul

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm using `@EnableOAuth2Sso` to authenticate a user with a third party authentication server on the Zuul server. I need to pass user info from Zuul to the routed servers. I've set up the request endpoint `/userinfo` to return a jsonified representation of a flattened version of the userinfo from the third party. How do I get this userinfo to one of the resource servers?

**What I've tried so far**:

I've tried making a request using the `@LoadBalanced @Bean RestTemplate` been. However, I get redirected to the third party for authorization. The `sensitive-headers` is set to none. I've checked which headers were going through:

```
["upgrade-insecure-requests","user-agent","accept","accept-language","cookie",
"authorization","x-forwarded-host","x-forwarded-proto",
"x-forwarded-prefix","x-forwarded-port","x-forwarded-for","accept-encoding",
"content-length", "host","connection"]
```

So, then I tried using `@LoadBalanced @Bean OAuth2RestTemplate`. I had to set the config `security.basic.enabled=false` to prevent the Authentication User Login Prompt from appearing. This produces `UserRedirectRequiredException`

### Resource Server

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> test3() {
    return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://zuul-server/userinfo", String.class);
}
```

### Zuul Server

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userinfo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public User getInfo(OAuth2Authentication auth) {
    return service.getUser(auth); // Returns User Object
}
```

### Additional Notes

The Resource Server has not been annotated with `@EnableResourceServer`. If it was, a forwarded request will result in `Invalid access token` error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have working on our system for passing Oauth2 JWT tokens.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_API")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
   }
```

And the config portion you might need.

```
services:
  path: /services/**
  serviceId: services
  stripPrefix: false
  sensitiveHeaders: true
auth:
  path: /oauth/**
  serviceId: saapi-auth-server
  stripPrefix: false
  sensitiveHeaders: true
```

There was very little documentation on this.  So it was really just hacking away at it until I could get it to pass tokens on.